# I get "DioError 404" error when running Flutter project on iOS, but I don't get any error on android

Tags: flutter, dio

I get "DioError 404" error while running Flutter project on iOS but I don't get any error on android. The project is running, but when I click on the widget connected to the Api, the application closes without any errors. On Android the whole project runs smoothly.
I'm using the easy_localization: ^3.0.0 and dio: ^4.0.6 packages. Do I need to add something extra for iOS?

Error:
[image]

[image]

> If I click on the item it closes the application.
> I only have this problem on IOS. hellppppp

> ```
> Flutter SDK version : 2.10.5       
>
> environment:
>       sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
>     
>     dependencies:
>       mobx: ^2.0.1
>       flutter_mobx: ^2.0.0
>       mobx_codegen: ^2.0.1+3
>       build_runner: ^2.0.6
>       easy_localization: ^3.0.0
>       shared_preferences: ^2.0.0
>       dio: ^4.0.6
>       connectivity: ^3.0.6
>       json_serializable: ^4.0.1
>       json_annotation: ^4.0.1
>       get_it: ^7.1.4
>       shimmer: ^2.0.0
>       auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
>       jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
>       either_option: ^2.0.1-dev.1
>       smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
>       persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
>       google_maps_flutter: 2.0.0
>       flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
>       favorite_button: ^0.0.4
>       provider: ^6.0.1
>       colorful_safe_area: ^0.3.0
>       animated_rotation: ^2.0.0
>       photo_view: ^0.13.0
>       another_flushbar: ^1.10.24
>       flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
>       flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
>       cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
>       bordered_text: ^2.0.0
>       sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
>       automatic_animated_list: ^1.0.0
>       share: ^2.0.4
>       expandable: ^5.0.1
>       url_launcher: ^6.0.17
>       flutter_tts: ^3.3.3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

Since I am using a device with Apple M1 processor, "google_maps_flutter: 2.0.0" M1 support is not available. I got rid of this issue by upgrading to "google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.5".

```
google_maps_flutter: 2.0.0 => google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.5
```

I don't understand what it has to do with Dio404 :/